# If one thread  closing the stream and another thread  getting started to read from the stream i get "Stream closed exception". How to solve the issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, filereader

I have a file. It sometimes happens that one thread has finsihed reading the file. The moment he is closing the reader another thread comes and try to read from the same stream associted with the reader. But then i get some

```
  stream already close exception.
```

How i can resolve such issues.

Like

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

How i can i create seprate stream for different threads.

Comment: Without code sample it is hard to help you, but it seems that you do not synchronize you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in my opinion you should not close the stream when a thread has finished its work. Just leave it open and close it when all the work is done.

Of course, since you are using the same stream you will need to synchronize access to the stream to prevent conflicts. You just need to use an object as a monitor. Like:

```
synchronized(monitor) {
    monitor.wait();   // wait for signal
}

// read from input stream

synchronized(monitor) {
    monitor.notify(); // release the next thread to start reading
}
```

Each thread will run this code. Then the main thread will call notify for the first thread to allow it to read and then if you start other threads they will wait for the previous one to finish.

Note that here I'm assuming you don't want to read from the file in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not read the same stream from two different threads.**

Each thread should have their own stream, and each close the stream when they're finished.  This allows each thread to manage the stream in their own thread.  Multiple threads trying to read from the same stream is just asking for trouble.

Comment: can i do something like public static synchronized void where the actual reading is performed

Comment: Each stream should be a local variable to its thread.  Do not share streams across threads.  Any object which uses a stream should not be shared across threads.  It's not a matter of giving you helpful code, but rather you need to start by designing it this way.

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  It would be bad.

Comment: @ErickRobertson, I must disagree with your statement *"Any object which uses a stream should not be shared across threads"*, for the obvious use case: a ConnectionPool in which each Connection object holds references to read and write streams. This is very good design, there's nothing wrong about it. Or would you recommend that each thread create a new connection each time it needs to send data to some server, and closes the connection right after the data has been sent?! Or maybe each thread should maintain an open connection, in a useless way to spend system resources?

Comment: @BrunoReis well, yes, but two handler threads would not be able to a get the same connection object from the pool at the same time.

Comment: @ErickRobertson - +1 for Ghostbusters reference

Comment: @MartinJames, that's what a resource pool is supposed to do, isn't it? Once someone borrows a resource, it cannot be borrowed again until it is released. Anyways, I disagree with you as well: suppose you use a Connection object (which holds a pair of streams) to send objects (messages) to a server; if you implement it properly, in a thread-safe manner, you could benefit from sharing this object among many threads, and it would manage concurrency issues internally. Again, this goes against Erick's original proposition, that an object holding/using a stream should not be shared.

Comment: All in all, the truth is: if you really understand how multithreading works, what the related issues are and how to avoid them, you can share almost anything (that makes sense sharing, obviously), and you might get a performance benefit from that. If you don't understand the dangers of multithreading, then don't do it alone, and ask for advice. Simple as that. The OP asked: "I have a threading problem, how can I solve it?", and the answer he gets is: "don't". It's not answering the question, is it?

Comment: @BrunoReis The OP's problem is with one file.  He doesn't need a resource pool - he needs to only use one thread to access his file.  I understand what you're saying, but this question does not warrant such a complicated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this in more than one thread, it will create one for each thread.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
// do some reading
br.close();
```

Comment: @user882196, You can wrap it to be a BufferedReader.

Comment: Yeah i know but my source returns InputStream reference only

Comment: also what if i close the bufferedreader by doing br.close(). Will the InputStreamReader will also get closed by itself and release all it's resources.

Comment: If you br.close() the FileReader gets closed (it is an InputStreamReader and contains a FileInputStream which also get closed)  Only the stream in that thread is closed and if the file is open in another thread, that is not affected.